# chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() function example

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a small Chrome extension that needs to run in the background. However, I understand that that isn't possible when I'm using a popup. After some reading it seems that the best option is to create `popup.js` in order run the `background.js`, using `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` function.

Can someone please show me an example of how it's done?

here's the manifest:

```
"browser_action": {
"permissions": ["background"],
"default_popup": "popup.html"},
"options_page": "options.html",
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent" : true
}
```

I've included the popup.js reference in `popup.html`:

```
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

And created a variable in `popup.js`

```
var bkg = chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage();
```

so now I need a way to activate the `background.js`
Do I need to run the relevant function inside `background.js` from `popup.js`, 
or give a general command for the `background.js` to run?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Note that this solution is OK if you do not have `"persistent": false` in your `manifest.json`. Otherwise see the answer from @Pawelmhm

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you need to call function from background in your popup. Here's a simple example which demonstrates how it works.

**background.js**

```
function backgroundFunction () {
    return "hello from the background!"
}
```

**popup.js**

```
(function () {
    var otherWindows = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
    console.log(otherWindows.backgroundFunction()); 
})();
```

When you inspect your popup.js you'll see "hello from the background!" in your console. [GetBackgroundPage()](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-getBackgroundPage) simply returns window object for your background page, as you probably know all variables are attached to this window object so in this way you will get access to function defined in background scripts.

There is a sample code [demonstrating this in chrome documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html) see [Idle Simple Example](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/idle/idle_simple.zip) and look at file [history.js](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/idle/idle_simple/history.js)

Comment: Thank you #Pawelmhm, but as my background.js code is inside window.onload, the call from popup.js can't seem to reach the function. When I remove window.onload, I get the 'onclick' of null error, no matter where I place the script tag on the popup.html.

Comment: @NimrodSarda: It is diffecult for someone to guess what you might be wrong with your code, if they don't see it.

Answer (score 5):

The background page is loaded then you extension is loaded into Chrome.

Consider the popup page just as a normal web-page: here, you need to use [chrome.runtime](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html) to make requests to the background page.

Usually, I do it using an implicit (temporal) or explicit (permanent) channel. With temporal channel:

***popup.js***

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (answer) { /* your code */ });
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({cmd: "shutdown"});
```

***background.js***

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request) {
    if (request.cmd === "shutdown") {
        shutdown();
    }
});
```

With permanent channel:

***popup.js***

```js
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "myChannel"});

port.onMessage.addListener(function (answer) { /* your code */ });
port.postMessage({cmd: "shutdown"});
```

***background.js***

```js
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
    port.onMessage.addListener(function (request) {
        if (request.cmd === "shutdown") {
            shutdown();
        }
    }
});
```

**UPD.** While this way of content-backgrounf communication is fully functional, the current specs advice using `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage()` to call a function in the background script is the requests shouldn't be asynchronous (thus, less coding is needed and easier to read the code). See [the manual](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) and other answers to this post to clarify this matter.

Comment: `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage()` is the preferred way, should not be used **only** with event-pages. It works equally well with persistent background-pages, so it can always be used, regardless of the type of background-page. `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()`, on the other, hand cannot be used on event-pages. (I'm not saying you meant otherwise, just putting a little more emphasis on it.)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this matter. I have modified my answer so that it does not contain the misleading statements anymore.

Comment: The advantage of `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` over `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage` is that the first one is synchronous. Coding in a synchronous way initially leads to clearer-to-understand code. However, synchronous code can usually not be made asynchronous again without efforts, so if you're developing a new extension, use `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(callback)`.

Comment: @lexasss Your answer shows [`chrome.runtime.connect`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-connect), but no corresponding [`chrome.runtime.onConnect`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onConnect) event. So, the message will be lost.

Comment: Your are right, I mixed codes from 2 of my extensions. I modified the code, hope this is finally correct.

Comment: @RobW: By "advantage" do you mean "disadvantage" ? :D (At the very least is should be "difference" (imo), although I strongly feel that being asynchronous is an advantage.)

Comment: @ExpertSystem If you want to immediately get access to a variable, then a synchronous `getBackgroundPage()` allows you to write a simple getter. With an asynchronous method, the getter needs to pass the value back to a callback. This affects all functions that (indirectly) depend on this getter function, because the whole call stack needs to be able to handle the asynchronous flow. Synchronous functions can be used in sync and async functions, whereas async functions can generally only be used in async functions. So yes, I really meant "advantage", because sync methods can more easily be used.

Comment: @RobW: Sure both have advantages, but I feel that async's advantages (if properly implemented and used) by far outweight those of sync. E.g. making it _easy_ to develop _less_ efficient and responsive apps isn't so "advantageous" after all. (I don't imply that ease of use and readability don't have their merits - somethig you get, something you lose.)

Comment: I'm downvoting this answer, since while it is correct - it does not attempt to answer the original question.